# Насколько хорошим тоном является добавление условий в счётчик for()?

Tags: c++, условия, for

Пишу программу, в которой очень бы хотелось использовать подобную конструкцию (пример кода), но я не уверен, что это хороший стиль программирования, не могли бы вы подсказать, так ли это?

```
for(int i = 0; i < size && statement1 && statement2; i++)
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: нормальный стиль

Comment: Если условия для продолжения цикла  нужны, то их нужно добавлять. Хороший тон тут непричем

Comment: Есть некоторый риск, что при чтении будут упущены второе и третье условия, как не характерные для циклов - счетчиков. Отдельный if/break более наглядный.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это вопрос стиля и личных предпочтений. Я лично считаю, что удобочитаемость кода получается намного выше, если заголовок "поискового" цикла описывает весь потенциальный диапазон, по которому производится поиск, а собственно проверка частных поисковых условий (которые могу вызвать "досрочное" завершение цикла) делается в теле цикла.

Например, найти символ `'a'` в строке `s`

```
unsigned i;
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
  if (s[i] == 'a')
    break;
```

а не

```
unsigned i;
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0' && s[i] != 'a'; ++i)
  ;
```

То есть заголовок цикла описывает **где** мы ищем, а тело цикла описывает **что** мы ищем. Разумеется, разграничение между этими понятиями не всегда является четким и, еще раз, это вопрос стиля и личных предпочтений.

Answer (score 4):

На практике очень часто встречаемая конструкция.

Однако, идеоматически цикл `for` используется для *известного перед началом цикла* числа повторов, а для цикла, в котором условие завершения становится истинным при вычислениях (в т.ч. проверке значения элементов массива) предназначены циклы `while` и `do { ... } while();`

Если `statement1` и `statement2` из вашего вопроса не меняются внутри цикла, то лучше вынести их в `if` перед циклом `for`.

Иначе, лучше написать цикл `while`
(впрочем, это дело вкуса, реально никто за такой `for` ругать не будет).

Answer (score 0):

Отдельные условия выхода из цикла, имхо, более наглядны - создают ощущения повествования, что за чем следует и когда в итерации может сработать условие выхода.